# PDF form fields: Separate/Extract widget dictionary from field dictionary

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfstamper, openpdf, pdf-manipulation

According to the PDF spec it is possible to merge the widget dictionary and the field dictionary when there is only one associated widget annotation. Is there some support by iText / openPDF to separate the two again? (Low level API would suffice).

**Update**: Ok so there seems to be no convienient method for it. But what about the following entries which does exist in both dictionaries:

- `AA` (additional actions) are defined in (widget) annotation dictionary and in the field dictionary - so when separating where to put it?
- `Parent` - both field and annotation define a parent - so when separating where to put it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no explicit support for that. You can of course use the iText/OpenPdf lowlevel objects to separate field and widget. Beware, though: Before PDF-2.0 an isolated widget annotation could always also be considered as nameless field with a merged-in widget annotation.

Comment: Ah interesting in 2.0 the field name is required... Regarding the separation of the two I need to manually split them up...Argh tried to avoid that manual task but okay :-)

Comment: @mkl Do you know when separating both dicts where to put `AA` and `Parent`?

Comment: When you split, the field keeps the parent entry and the widget refers to the field as parent. AA on the other hand is specified to have the identical meaning, whether it's in the field or the widget. Thus, either one should do, shouldn't it?